# How to overwrite column using sql query instead of api

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example, I have a table customers in which there is a column `name` and column `last_name`.

I want to concatenate both these columns and overwrite the column `name` with the result of the concatenation.

In Spark sql api we can do [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623461/how-to-overwrite-entire-existing-column-in-spark-dataframe-with-new-column):

```scala
customers.withColumn("name", concat(col("name"), lit(" "), col("last_name")))
```

Doing the following in sql query:

```sql
select *, concat(name, " ", last_name) AS name from customers
```

will instead add another column name in the dataframe. So at the end there are two columns with the same name `name`.

Is there a way in sql query to overwrite the existing column without adding a new one ?

Comment: No, you can't do that using SQL. You'll have to specify explicitly each column in the select clause.

Comment: @blackbishop Of course one can. He just has to stop using `*` which `SELECT`s everything. Just see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Both methods work.

Using the SQL method works. Don't use `*`, that will include the old columns, just do your `CONCAT` and rename with `AS`.

```scala
customers.createOrReplaceTempView("customers")
spark.sql("SELECT CONCAT(name, ' ', last_name) AS name FROM customers").show()
//+--------+
//|    name|
//+--------+
//|John Doe|
//|Jane Doe|
//+--------+
```

`withColumn` also works, and similarly there is a [`withColumnRenamed`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame).

So perform your operations as you wish, creating a new column and then drop the original column(s) and rename the new column.

```scala
// Problem Setup
val customers = = Seq(("John", "Doe"), ("Jane", "Doe")).toDF("name", "last_name")

customers.show()
//+----+---------+
//|name|last_name|
//+----+---------+
//|John|      Doe|
//|Jane|      Doe|
//+----+---------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, col, concat}

customers.withColumn(
  "name_last_name", concat(col("name"), lit(" "), col("last_name"))
).drop("name", "last_name").withColumnRenamed("name_last_name", "name").show()
//+--------+
//|    name|
//+--------+
//|John Doe|
//|Jane Doe|
//+--------+
```

Of course you can go ahead and do the operation itself in the `withColumn` function call, giving the newly generated column the label `name` replaces the old one, but you'll still have to drop `last_name`.

```scala
customers.withColumn(
  "name", concat(col("name"), lit(" "), col("last_name"))
).drop("last_name").show()
//+--------+
//|    name|
//+--------+
//|John Doe|
//|Jane Doe|
//+--------+
```